# Make sandbox classified?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, sandbox

I just saw the merged sandbox, and *woah...*

I notice that in the OP post that the active challenge is classified into 3.

  King Of The Hill

  Codegolf

  Others

Will it be wise if we make 3 sandbox? One sandbox for each type? So we have One sandbox full of KOTH. One sandbox full of codegolf and one sandbox for others (popularity, puzzle, troll, etc).

15 pages of sandbox is a little bit, *intimidating* for me. Classification may help.

Comment: I agree that the list is intimidating at first sight. You can make it much less so by sorting by "active" so that you only see the recently updated posts (which are the ones that need feedback). Then abandoned posts and posts that have already gone to the main site go to the bottom and you don't see them.

This way you can quickly give feedback to several recently posted or recently improved posts without having to wade through to find them.

Comment: Related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/957/having-several-active-sandboxes-by-tag

Answer (score 5):

## The sandbox works better unified

Although I understand that it can be intimidating at first glance, this can be much improved by sorting by "active" and I think that is sufficient. I believe there is much more benefit to keeping a single unified sandbox than there would be from splitting it.

If someone wants to drop in to the sandbox and give some quick feedback, they are going to drop in to just one of the 3 sandboxes, give feedback on a few posts until they find they've run out of time, and then neglect the other two sandboxes, even though that was never their intention. Keeping it together means that what is prioritised is what has been recently updated, not one challenge type over another.

Also, people who are unfamiliar with a given challenge type may still have useful feedback, which they will give if they see the challenge on the list, but might never see if they don't feel the other sandbox is their place. So it's better for everyone, whether they are interested in all challenge types or just one or two.

The site and community benefit from more people, and more questions. I want everyone to be encouraged to ask any kind of question, and for everyone to see the kinds of questions they don't ask themselves. This way there are more ideas shared and a code golf may be inspired by a King of the Hill challenge, or a King of the Hill may be inspired by a fastest code challenge. This way a sandbox post that turns out to be unsuitable can still be scavenged for spare parts so that we get more questions overall.

I'm against anything that makes the community more divided, even indirectly.

Comment: One more point: it seems impractical to have 3/multiple [meta-tag:featured] sandboxes.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I hadn't considered the practicalities since I'm so against the idea already, but that's a good point. Also the sandbox requires a certain amount of upkeep, which would be more work if split.

Comment: I personally have little interest in sandboxing King of the Hill challenges, so I would like a way to "drop in to just one of the 3 sandboxes". As is, I have to scroll and page past a sea of long KOTH posts that are always at the top (understandably, given how much care is needed to make them) just to find a code-golf. Not sure if sorting by active would change this.

Comment: @xnor would it help you, once sorted by active, to do an intrapage search for tag:code-golf?

Comment: I don't feel splitting the sandbox would solve your problem, as there are also some code golf challenges several screens long. If you want to devote a short period of time in a break to feedback on a brief code golf description you might save time by clicking on the intrapage links in the directory at the top of the sandbox. Then you can only look at those under the code golf section of the directory, and just press back and try the next if you hit a golf post too long for the time you have spare.